# using a new path with execve to run ls command

Tags: c, path, exec, execve

I am trying to use execve to run the ls command. Currently I'm running it with the following arguments:

```
execve(args[0], args, env_args)
//args looks like {"ls", "-l", "-a", NULL}
//env_args looks like {"PATH=/bin", "USER=me", NULL}
```

What I expected this to do was run the ls command using my new env_args meaning that it would look up ls in my PATH.  However, this code actually doesn't do anything and when I run the code it just returns to my command prompt without output.

Using the same args[] I was using execvp and ls worked and searched my current path.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

What I am trying to do is write my own shell program where I can create and export my own environment and have exec use the environment I have defined in a char**.  Essentially I am writing my own functions to operate on env_args to add and remove vars and when I call exec i want to be able to call exec on {"ls", "-l", NULL} and have it look down my new environments path variable for a valid program called ls.  I hope this explains what I am doing a little better.  I don't think the extern environ var will work for me in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `execve()` function does not look at PATH; for that, you need `execvp()`.  Your program was failing to execute `ls`, and apparently you don't report failures to execute a program after the `execve()`.  Note that members of the `exec*()` family of functions only return on error.

You'd get the result you expected (more or less) if you ran the program with `/bin` as your current directory (because `./ls` - aka `ls` - would then exist).

You need to provide the pathname of the executable in the first argument to `execve()`, after finding it using an appropriate PATH setting.

Or continue to use `execvp()`, but set the variable `environ` to your new environment.  Note that `environ` is unique among POSIX global variables in that is it not declared in any header.

```
extern char **environ;

environ = env_args;
execvp(args[0], &args[0]);
```

You don't need to save the old value and restore it; you're in the child process and switching its environment won't affect the main program (shell).

---

This seems to work as I'd expect - and demonstrates that the original code behaves as I'd expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

int main(void)
{
    char *args[]     = { "ls", "-l", "-a", NULL };
    char *env_args[] = { "PATH=/bin", "USER=me", NULL };

    execve(args[0], args, env_args);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops!\n");

    environ = env_args;
    execvp(args[0], &args[0]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Oops again!\n");

    return -1;
}
```

I get an 'Oops!' followed by the listing of my directory.  When I create an executable `ls` in my current directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Haha!"
```

then I don't get the 'Oops!' and do get the 'Haha!'.

Comment: ok, but say i want to have execvp look at a different path than the one defined in my environment? that is the kind of functionality i am looking for

Comment: On second thought, I don't think environ is what i want.  I'm still not sure how to do this.

Comment: Why do you think that setting the environment is not the answer?  Where is `ls` found on your machine?

Comment: ok Jonathan, I think you are right.  I think i just misunderstood what execve was supposed to do. I thought you could essentially pass a PATH to it in the new environment.

Comment: Just tried it out. It looks like I can make this work. THANK YOU!