# Add directory to the PATH for execvp()

Tags: c, unix, path, terminal, execvp

I am writing a small console-like program in C, along with implementations for ls, tac and dir.

I use execvp() function to override the forked children of the process, but when the user inserts one of the above 3 commands, I have to execute my own version, not the one from the system.

I know that execvp() uses the system PATH variable to search in different locations for the executable file. Can I somehow edit the PATH in my program, so I could add a custom directory as the first place for execvp() search?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a nice explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630551/using-a-new-path-with-execve-to-run-ls-command

Comment: Can't you just put the full path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `PATH` with `setenv` -- but mind you, it might be simpler to just check for those commands explicitly before doing the `exec`.